# vb.net fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert, fatal-error

```
 Public Sub StokKartiKayit()
        Try
            BaglantiKontrol()


            Dim StokAd As String = StokKartiTanimForm.txtStokAdi.Text.ToUpper
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream

            StokKartiTanimForm.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, StokKartiTanimForm.PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)


            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO stok_karti_tbl (KategoriID,ParcaID,StokAdi,Resim) Values(@Kategori,@Parca,@Stok,@img)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Kategori", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = UrunKategoriID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parca", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ParcaID
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stok", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StokAd
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = ms.ToArray()

            con.Open()

            If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1 Then
                MsgBox("Stok Kartı Bilgileri Kayıt Edilmiştir...", vbInformation, "MoTap")
            Else
                MsgBox("Lütfen Resim Formatını Kontrol Ediniz. Kayıt İşleminde Sorun Oluştu...", vbCritical, "MoTap")
            End If

            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I have a function like this. When I try to add an image, it gives me a Fatal Error. But when I remove the image column, I don't have any problems. I couldn't solve the problem, I would be grateful if you could help.

Comment: What is the full `ex.Message`? That will have a lot more help on the what is going on.

Comment: Also, you should not be using the same connection throughout your app. ADO.Net does connection pooling for you in the background, and re-using the same connection breaks that process and actually makes things slower and less efficient. It really is better to create a brand new connection object for most queries.

Comment: ex.Message=fatal error encountered during command execution

Comment: And after that? The message should include more.

Comment: Unfortunately, it only gives me this message, there is no other explanation

Comment: I am having a problem when saving the image. I don't have any problems when I cancel the @img parameter.

Comment: Change MsgBox(ex.Message) to MsgBox(ex.ToString), that will give you a whole lot more info

Answer (score 1):

Without the exact exception, it is hard to guess, but the memory stream could be handled like this:

```
private byte[] imageAsByteArray(Image img)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then store the image into the database using this:

```
var data = imageAsByteArray(StokKartiTanimForm.PictureBox1.Image);
MySqlParameter blobParam = new MySqlParameter("@img", MySqlDbType.Blob, data.Length);
blobParam.Value = data;
```